# Formatting and validating a date in JSF

Tags: java, validation, jsf, date, datetime

So I want to format my dateinputfield as "dd-MM-yyyy" and then validate that the date is not before tomorrow.

This is the relevant code in my view:

```
   <h:inputText id="dueDate" required="true" value="#{submitRepairBean.dueDate}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>   
                <f:validator validatorId="be.kdg.repaircafe.validators.DueDateValidator"/>
   </h:inputText>
```

This is my custom validator:

```
@FacesValidator("be.kdg.repaircafe.validators.DueDateValidator")
public class DueDateValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        System.out.println(value.toString()); //For some reason this prints Wed Jul 23 02:00:00 CEST 2014 when inputting 23-07-2014
        DateTime date = new DateTime(value.toString());
        long dueDateMillis = date.getMillis();
        long oneDayMillis = 86400000;
        Calendar tomorrowMidnight = new GregorianCalendar();
        // reset hour, minutes, seconds and millis
        tomorrowMidnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        tomorrowMidnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        tomorrowMidnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        tomorrowMidnight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        tomorrowMidnight.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        if (dueDateMillis + oneDayMillis < tomorrowMidnight.getTimeInMillis()) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("You can not have something repaired before tomorrow!"));
        }

    }
```

Now the thing I don't understand is why it doesn't print in the converted format (dd-MM-yyyy), even then I don't care so much as long as I get the correct amount of milliseconds. 
However, the DateTime constructor then throws an exception that the date is in an invalid format.

I've tried using SimpleDateFormat as well, with no luck.

Comment: try converting your value with Date date = (Date) value; to a date-object of java.util.Date and then call new DateTime(date);

Comment: you also could use as validatorid some more representative id like dateValidator or birthdayValidator

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter  it will show you the date in this format on the page (in the jsp/html page). What it does, is converting the date in a string in the format dd-mm-yyyy. When you pass the calue in the validate function, it is not converted in the string in the format dd-MM-yyyy. it is a date, dueDate is a date, so by printing value.toString() is just converts the date value to a string. So the object is a date and just by casting to Date is should work. if you want in the code to print it in the format dd-MM-yyyy try this

```
Date date = (Date) value;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String strDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDate );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@FacesValidator("validator.dateValidator")
public class DateValidator implements Validator, ClientValidator {
    final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    public DateValidator() {
    }
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        if (value == null || StringUtils.isEmpty((String) value.toString())) {
            return;
        }       
        SimpleDateFormat objDf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        objDf.setLenient(false);

        try {
            try {           
        Date data = new Date();
        data.setDate(data.getDate() + 1);
        if(objDf.parse(value.toString()).before(data)){
            ((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("You can not have something repaired before tomorrow!"));
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {

        ((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(MessageUtils.ALERTA, "Data informada não Válida!", ""));

    }       
        } catch (ParseException e) {            
             throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid Date!"));
        }
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getMetadata() {
        return null;
    }
    public String getValidatorId() {
        return "validator.dateValidator";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good and common practice in Stackoverflow to add textual explanations to answers. If you don't, you'll stand a chance it will be downvoted and closed.